# Reading from STDIN, performing commands, then Outputting to STDOUT in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to:

- Accept STDIN in my script from a pipe
- save it to a temp file so that I don't modify the original source
- perform operations on the temp file to generate some output
- output to STDOUT

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=$(cat)

sed 's/the/THE/g' <temp

echo "$temp"
```

Right now, I am just trying to get it to be able to replace all occurences of "the" with "THE".

Here is the sample text:

```
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy

brown dog the quick

brown fox jumped

over
```

Here is my command line:

```
cat test.txt | ./hwscript >hwscriptout
```

"test.txt" contains the sample text, "hwscript" is the script, "hwscriptout" is the output

However, when I look at the output file, nothing has changed (all of occurences of "the" remain uncapitalized). When I do the sed command on the command line instead of the script, it works though. I also tried to use $(sed) instead of sed but when I did that, the command returned an error:

"./hwscript: line 5: s/the/THE/g: no such file or directory"

I have tried to search for a solution but could not find one.

Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `<temp` reads from a file named temp, not the variable.

Comment: I replaced temp with $(temp) but it still did not work, I also tried replacing sed with $(sed) and that did not work either

Comment: That will just try to use the first word in `$temp` as the name of a file to process. `<` is for redirecting to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
temp=$(sed 's/the/THE/' <<<"$temp")
```

or

```
temp=$(printf "%s" "$temp" | sed 's/the/THE/')
```

You were telling `sed` to process a file named `temp`, not the contents of the variable `$temp`. You also weren't saving the result anywhere, so `echo "$temp"` simply prints the old value

Comment: Emacs won't let me type "<<<", it always auto-corrects to < < and inserts EOF, I'm not sure what it's doing

Comment: Turn off electric mode. I guess it doesn't know about that bash extension.

Comment: I've added how to do it without the bash `<<<` extension.

Answer (score 2):

> save it to a temp file so that I don't modify the original source

Anything received via `stdin` is just a *stream of data*, disconnected from wherever it originated from: whatever you do with that stream has *no effect whatsoever on its origin*.

Thus, there is **no need to involve a temporary file - simply modify `stdin` input as needed**.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/the/THE/g'  # without a filename operand or pipe input, this will read from stdin
# Without an output redirection, the output will go to stdout.
```

As you can tell, in this simple case you may as well use the `sed` command directly, without creating a script.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it as you described it

```
#!/bin/sh

# Read the input and append to tmp file
while read LINE; do
   echo ${LINE} >> yourtmpfile
done

# Edit the file in place
sed -i '' 's/the/THE/g' yourtmpfile

#Output the result
cat yourtmpfile
rm yourtmpfile
```

And here is a simpler way without a tmp file

```
#!/bin/sh

# Read the input and output the line after sed
while read LINE; do
   echo ${LINE} | sed 's/the/THE/g'
done
```

Comment: The above will destroy Tokyo and lure sailors onto rocks. Too many issues to list, just don't do it.